# Compositeness tests for specific classes of generalized repunit numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Can you provide  proofs or counterexamples for the following two claims:

*First claim*

Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}\right)$ .

Let $N_p(b)=\frac{b^p+1}{b+1}$ ,  where $p$ is an odd prime and $b$ is an odd natural number greater than one .

CASE(1). $b \equiv 1,9 \pmod{12}$ , or $b \equiv 3,7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ , or $b\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod{12}$ , or $b \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,11 \pmod{12}$ .

CASE(2). $b \equiv 3,7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ , or $ b\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,11 \pmod{12}$ , or $b \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,7 \pmod{12}$ .

Let $S_i=P_b(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=P_b(4)$ . Suppose $N_p(b)$ is prime , then :

$\bullet$ $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{b}(4) \pmod {N_p(b)}$ if Case(1) holds ;

$\bullet$ $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{b+2}(4) \pmod {N_p(b)}$ if Case(2) holds ;

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVkMEKwjAQRO-C_xA8yK6NSFJFpO4n6KV3wdRKC60JbVEEP95tFWm1Il42zOybCYkhPxgOXDND0hNnsyiJzbVM4jMYqaRG3mwJzM55CmdgeLITVQUpPi9JmsXAak1uqmRIG3uAnppwplFuMWDSo6YhPQLUMG81Eilxu4mWXmFtdBD_DVmiGI8bw8l5XfGItIhFDcCD6N7y1EuBHyGlfqWYQJT8gJD6v0y6Ij1VMHKFNXuTXQXrPB69_MjmzpZpxda3Hk__3YR3OECCJg==&lang=gp) .

---

*Second claim*

Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot \left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4}\right)^{m}\right)$ .

Let $M_p(a)=\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ ,  where $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is an odd natural number greater than one .

CASE(1). $a \equiv 3,11 \pmod{12}$ , or $a \equiv 5,9 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ , or $a\equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod{12}$ , or $a \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,11 \pmod{12}$ .

CASE(2). $a \equiv 5,9 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ , or $ a\equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,11 \pmod{12}$ , or $a \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,7 \pmod{12}$ .

Let $S_i=P_a(S_{i-1})$ with $S_0=P_a(4)$ . Suppose $M_p(a)$ is prime , then :

$\bullet$ $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{a}(4) \pmod {M_p(a)}$ if Case(1) holds ;

$\bullet$ $S_{p-1} \equiv P_{a-2}(4) \pmod {M_p(a)}$ if Case(2) holds ;

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVkM0KwjAQhO-C71A8yK5GSqIiUvcRespdSGukhWpCWxTBh3fbUvEX8bJhZ74Z2BiaR8OBb6cmNfGuSDObXKrMnsAIKRSyExOYrZ9JDMHwZCWtS5L8nrO8sMDbhtgXmmK3gw81OlQoYoyYnFLbkO8BGphdhUTz4HoNHnYpsVGemOULs8ZgPG4FLxZNpos8EKsGgI7oavsK3wP4FpK_QlJySvABmj5_mfBlfqxh5EuXmKS4BLwf7Oiup-7gXZXXLH3rmam_m_AGJPmCHQ==&lang=gp) .

---

I have tested these claims for many random values from [this list](http://www.primenumbers.net/Henri/us/MersFermus.htm) .

**EDIT**

A command line program that implements these two tests can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/Generep) .

Comment: Your questions and the answer below have a great merit (+1). I didn't read these in detail, because these have deep details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two claims are true.

Let us first prove by induction that
$$S_i=\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}\tag1$$
where $\alpha=2-\sqrt 3,\beta=2+\sqrt 3$ with $\alpha\beta=1$.

$(1)$ holds for $i=0$ since
$$S_0=P_b(4)=2^{-b}\left((4-2\sqrt 3)^b+(4+2\sqrt 3)^b\right)=\alpha^{b}+\beta^{b}$$

Supposing that $(1)$ holds for some $i$ gives

$$\small\begin{align}S_{i+1}&=P_b(S_i)
\\&=2^{-b}\cdot \left(\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\sqrt{\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}\right)^2-4}\right)^{b}+\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}+\sqrt{\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}\right)^2-4}\right)^{b}\right)
\\&=2^{-b}\cdot \left(\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\sqrt{\left(\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\alpha^{b^{i+1}}\right)^2}\right)^{b}+\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}+\sqrt{\left(\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\alpha^{b^{i+1}}\right)^2}\right)^{b}\right)
\\&=2^{-b}\cdot \left(\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\left(\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\alpha^{b^{i+1}}\right)\right)^{b}+\left(\alpha^{b^{i+1}}+\beta^{b^{i+1}}+\left(\beta^{b^{i+1}}-\alpha^{b^{i+1}}\right)\right)^{b}\right)
\\&=\alpha^{b^{i+2}}+\beta^{b^{i+2}}\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

For the first claim, let $N:=N_p(b)=\frac{b^p+1}{b+1}$.

Then, we have, from $(1)$,

$$\small\begin{align}S_{p-1}
&=\alpha^{b^{p}}+\beta^{b^{p}}=\alpha^{N(b+1)-1}+\beta^{N(b+1)-1}=\alpha\beta\left(\alpha^{N(b+1)-1}+\beta^{N(b+1)-1}\right)=\beta(\alpha^{N})^{b+1}+\alpha(\beta^{N})^{b+1}
\\&=\beta\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N}\binom Ni2^{N-i}(-\sqrt 3)^i\right)^{b+1}
+\alpha\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N}\binom Ni2^{N-i}(\sqrt 3)^i\right)^{b+1}\end{align}$$

Here, there are integers $A,B$ divisible by $N$ such that

$\small\begin{align}S_{p-1}&=\beta\left(2^{N}+A-\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}+\alpha\left(2^N+A+\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}
\\\\&=2\left(\left(2^{N}+A-\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}+\left(2^{N}+A+\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}\right)
\\&\qquad +\sqrt 3\ \left(\left(2^{N}+A-\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}-\left(2^{N}+A+\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{b+1}\right)
\\\\&=2\sum_{i=0}^{b+1}\binom {b+1}i(2^N+A)^{b+1-i}\left(\left(-\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^i+\left(\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^i\right)
\\&\qquad +\sqrt 3\ \sum_{i=0}^{b+1}\binom {b+1}i(2^N+A)^{b+1-i}\left(\left(-\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^i-\left(\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^i\right)
\\\\&=2\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j}(2^N+A)^{b+1-2j}\cdot 2\left(\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{2j}
\\&\qquad -\sqrt 3\ \sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j-1}(2^N+A)^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 2\left(\sqrt 3\ \left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)\right)^{2j-1}
\\\\&=4\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j}(2^N+A)^{b+1-2j}\cdot 3^j\left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)^{2j}
\\&\qquad -2\sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j-1}(2^N+A)^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\left(B+3^{(N-1)/2}\right)^{2j-1}
\\\\&\equiv 4\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j}(2^N)^{b+1-2j}\cdot 3^j\left(3^{(N-1)/2}\right)^{2j}
\\&\qquad -2\sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j-1}(2^N)^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\left(3^{(N-1)/2}\right)^{2j-1}\pmod N
\\\\&\equiv 4\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j}\cdot 2^{b+1-2j}\cdot 3^j
-2\cdot \color{red}{3^{(N-1)/2}}\sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j-1}\cdot 2^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\pmod N\qquad\qquad(2)\end{align}$

Now, we have that

$\small\begin{align}P_b(4)&=\alpha^b+\beta^b=\alpha\beta(\alpha^b+\beta^b)=\beta\alpha^{b+1}+\alpha\beta^{b+1}
\\&=2\left((2-\sqrt 3)^{b+1}+(2+\sqrt 3)^{b+1}\right)+\sqrt 3\ \left((2-\sqrt 3)^{b+1}-(2+\sqrt 3)^{b+1}\right)
\\&=2\sum_{i=0}^{b+1}\binom{b+1}{i}2^{b+1-i}((-\sqrt 3)^i+(\sqrt 3)^i)
+\sqrt 3\sum_{i=0}^{b+1}\binom{b+1}{i}2^{b+1-i}((-\sqrt 3)^i-(\sqrt 3)^i)
\\&=2\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j}2^{b+1-2j}\cdot 2(\sqrt 3)^{2j}
-\sqrt 3\ \sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j-1}2^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 2(\sqrt 3)^{2j-1}
\\&=4\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j}2^{b+1-2j}\cdot 3^j
-2\cdot \color{red}1\sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j-1}2^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (3)\end{align}$

and that

$\small\begin{align}P_{b+2}(4)&=\alpha^{b+2}+\beta^{b+2}=\alpha\cdot \alpha^{b+1}+\beta\cdot\beta^{b+1}
\\&=2\left((2-\sqrt 3)^{b+1}+(2+\sqrt 3)^{b+1}\right)-\sqrt 3\ \left((2-\sqrt 3)^{b+1}-(2+\sqrt 3)^{b+1}\right)
\\&=4\sum_{j=0}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j}2^{b+1-2j}\cdot 3^j-2\cdot \color{red}{(-1)}\sum_{j=1}^{(b+1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j-1}2^{b+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (4)\end{align}$

It follows from $(2)(3)(4)$ that

- if $3^{(N-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod N$, then $S_{p-1}\equiv P_b(4)\pmod N$
- if $3^{(N-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod N$, then $S_{p-1}\equiv P_{b+2}(4)\pmod N$

Now, since
$$\small N=b^{p-1}-b^{p-2}+\cdots -b+1\equiv\begin{cases}1&\text{if $b\equiv 0,1\pmod 3$}\\\\1&\text{if $b\equiv 2,p\equiv 1\pmod 3$}\\\\2&\text{if $b\equiv 2,p\equiv 2\pmod 3$}\end{cases}
\equiv\begin{cases}1&\text{if $b\equiv 1\pmod 4$}\\\\1&\text{if $b\equiv 3,p\equiv 1\pmod 4$}\\\\3&\text{if $b\equiv 3,p\equiv 3\pmod 4$}\end{cases}$$
we have

- If $b \equiv 1,9 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $b \equiv 3,7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $b\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $b \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,11 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{\pm 1}{\pm 1}=1$
- If $b \equiv 3,7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1$
- If $ b\equiv 5 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,11 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$
- If $b \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,7 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(N-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(N-1)/2}}{\left(\frac N3\right)}=\frac{\mp 1}{\pm 1}=-1$

Since $3^{(N-1)/2}=1$ holds in CASE(1), $S_{p-1}\equiv P_b(4)\pmod{N_p(b)}$ holds in CASE(1).

Since $3^{(N-1)/2}=-1$ holds in CASE(2), $S_{p-1}\equiv P_{b+2}(4)\pmod{N_p(b)}$ holds in CASE(2).

---

For the second claim, let $M:=M_p(a)=\frac{a^p-1}{a-1}$.

Then, similarly as above, we have, from $(1)$,

$$\small\begin{align}S_{p-1}&=\alpha^{a^p}+\beta^{a^p}=\alpha^{M(a-1)+1}+\beta^{M(a-1)+1}=\alpha(\alpha^M)^{a-1}+\beta(\beta^M)^{a-1}
\\\\&\equiv 4\sum_{j=0}^{(a-1)/2}\binom {b+1}{2j}\cdot 2^{a-1-2j}\cdot 3^j
\\&\qquad +2\cdot \color{red}{3^{(M-1)/2}}\sum_{j=1}^{(a-1)/2}\binom {a-1}{2j-1}\cdot 2^{a-1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\pmod M\tag5\end{align}$$

Now, we have that
$$P_a(4)=4\sum_{j=0}^{(a+1)/2}\binom{a+1}{2j}2^{a+1-2j}\cdot 3^j+2\cdot \color{red}1\sum_{j=1}^{(a+1)/2}\binom{a+1}{2j-1}\cdot 2^{a+1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\tag6$$
and that
$$P_{a-2}(4)=4\sum_{j=0}^{(a-1)/2}\binom{b+1}{2j}2^{a-1-2j}\cdot 3^j+2\cdot \color{red}{(-1)}\sum_{j=1}^{(a-1)/2}\binom{a-1}{2j-1}\cdot 2^{a-1-(2j-1)}\cdot 3^j\tag7$$

It follows $(5)(6)(7)$ that

- if $3^{(M-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod M$, then $S_{p-1}\equiv P_a(4)\pmod{M}$
- if $3^{(M-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod M$, then $S_{p-1}\equiv P_{a-2}(4)\pmod{M}$

Now since
$$\small M=a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}+\cdots +a+1\equiv\begin{cases}1&\text{if $a\equiv 0,2\pmod 3$}\\\\1&\text{if $a\equiv 1,p\equiv 1\pmod 3$}\\\\2&\text{if $a\equiv 1,p\equiv 2\pmod 3$}\end{cases}\equiv\begin{cases}1&\text{if $a\equiv 1,p\equiv 1\pmod 4$}\\\\3&\text{if $a\equiv 1,p\equiv 3\pmod 4$}\\\\1&\text{if $a\equiv 3\pmod 4$}\end{cases}$$
we have

- If $a \equiv 3,11 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $a \equiv 5,9 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $a\equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,7 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$
- If $a \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 1,11 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{\pm 1}{\pm 1}=1$
- If $a \equiv 5,9 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{-1}{1}=-1$
- If $a\equiv 7 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,11 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$
- If $a \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$ and $p \equiv 5,7 \pmod{12}$, then $3^{(M-1)/2}=\frac{(-1)^{(M-1)/2}}{\left(\frac M3\right)}=\frac{\mp 1}{\pm 1}=-1$

Since $3^{(M-1)/2}=1$ holds in CASE(1), $S_{p-1}\equiv P_{a}(4)\pmod{M_p(b)}$ holds in CASE(1).

Since $3^{(M-1)/2}=-1$ holds in CASE(2), $S_{p-1}\equiv P_{a-2}(4)\pmod{M_p(b)}$ holds in CASE(2).